# Clear selected item of Telerik Rad Drop Down Tree - client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, treeview

I have a Telerik RadDropDownTree control.

```
<telerik:RadDropDownTree runat="server" ID="ddtEmpDepartment" ... >
</telerik:RadDropDownTree>
```

I am able to get the selected value:

```
var val = $find("<%=ddtEmpDepartment.ClientID %>").get_selectedValue();
```

But, I want to clear it's selected value, **client side**, what method should I use?

I have tried this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#clearTree', function() {
    var tree = $find("<%=ddtEmpDepartment.ClientID %>"); // --> OK
    tree.clear(); // Fails
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```js
var tree= $find("<%= ddtEmpDepartment.ClientID %>");
tree.get_entries().clear();
```